# How to change svg color without changing box-shadow color

Tags: html, css

I have the following snippet, when I hover, I have a blue left shadow which I want to keep that color.

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li > a, #app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li > ul > li > a {
    background-size: 16px 16px;
    background-position: 14px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    justify-content: space-between;
    line-height: 44px;
    min-height: 44px;
    padding: 0 12px 0 44px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    color: black;
    opacity: 0.57;
    flex: 1 1 0px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.nav-icon-files {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxNiAxNiIgd2lkdGg9IjE2IiB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMTYiPjxwYXRoIGQ9Im0xLjUgMmMtMC4yNSAwLTAuNSAwLjI1LTAuNSAwLjV2MTFjMCAwLjI2IDAuMjQgMC41IDAuNSAwLjVoMTNjMC4yNiAwIDAuNS0wLjI0MSAwLjUtMC41di05YzAtMC4yNS0wLjI1LTAuNS0wLjUtMC41aC02LjVsLTItMnoiIGZpbGw9IiMwMDAiLz48L3N2Zz4K);
}

#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li.active,
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a:hover,
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a:focus,
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a:active, 
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a.selected,
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a.active, 
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li.active > a, 
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a:hover > a,
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a:focus > a,
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a:active > a, 
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a.selected > a,
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a.active > a {
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: inset 4px 0 blue;
}

body{
  background: #1e272e;
}
```

```html
<div id="app-navigation">
    <ul class="with-icon">
        <li data-id="files" class="nav-files">
            <a href="#" class="nav-icon-files svg">Files</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is how I change the svg color:

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li > a, #app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li > ul > li > a {
    background-size: 16px 16px;
    background-position: 14px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    justify-content: space-between;
    line-height: 44px;
    min-height: 44px;
    padding: 0 12px 0 44px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    color: black;
    opacity: 0.57;
    flex: 1 1 0px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.nav-icon-files {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxNiAxNiIgd2lkdGg9IjE2IiB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMTYiPjxwYXRoIGQ9Im0xLjUgMmMtMC4yNSAwLTAuNSAwLjI1LTAuNSAwLjV2MTFjMCAwLjI2IDAuMjQgMC41IDAuNSAwLjVoMTNjMC4yNiAwIDAuNS0wLjI0MSAwLjUtMC41di05YzAtMC4yNS0wLjI1LTAuNS0wLjUtMC41aC02LjVsLTItMnoiIGZpbGw9IiMwMDAiLz48L3N2Zz4K);
}

#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li.active,
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a:hover,
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a:focus,
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a:active, 
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a.selected,
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a.active, 
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li.active > a, 
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a:hover > a,
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a:focus > a,
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a:active > a, 
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a.selected > a,
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a.active > a {
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: inset 4px 0 blue;
}

body{
  background: #1e272e;
}


/* CUSTOM */

.nav-icon-files{
    filter: invert(72%) sepia(3%) saturate(75%) hue-rotate(22deg) brightness(80%) contrast(91%);
}
```

```html
<div id="app-navigation">
    <ul class="with-icon">
        <li data-id="files" class="nav-files">
            <a href="#" class="nav-icon-files svg">Files</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now my icon color changed but also my `box-shadow`. How can I keep the original color ?

**EDIT:**

```
.nav-icon-files:before{
    filter: invert(72%) sepia(3%) saturate(75%) hue-rotate(22deg) brightness(80%) contrast(91%);
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxNiAxNiIgd2lkdGg9IjE2IiB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMTYiPjxwYXRoIGQ9Im0xLjUgMmMtMC4yNSAwLTAuNSAwLjI1LTAuNSAwLjV2MTFjMCAwLjI2IDAuMjQgMC41IDAuNSAwLjVoMTNjMC4yNiAwIDAuNS0wLjI0MSAwLjUtMC41di05YzAtMC4yNS0wLjI1LTAuNS0wLjUtMC41aC02LjVsLTItMnoiIGZpbGw9IiMwMDAiLz48L3N2Zz4K);
}
```

Comment: use the SVG as a pseudo element and apply filter there

Comment: What is a pseudo element ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Comment: @TemaniAfif I can't modify the HTML part

Comment: that's the purpose of pseudo element, you don't need to modifiy the HTML, it's all about CSS

Comment: I posted the pseudo element, but my icon is not showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your code a little and use pseudo element instead of background

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li > a, #app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li > ul > li > a {
    background-size: 16px 16px;
    background-position: 14px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    justify-content: space-between;
    line-height: 44px;
    min-height: 44px;
    padding: 0 12px 0 28px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    color: black;
    opacity: 0.57;
    flex: 1 1 0px;
    z-index: 100;
    color:#fff;
}

.nav-icon-files:before {
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    margin-right:5px;
    vertical-align:text-bottom;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxNiAxNiIgd2lkdGg9IjE2IiB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMTYiPjxwYXRoIGQ9Im0xLjUgMmMtMC4yNSAwLTAuNSAwLjI1LTAuNSAwLjV2MTFjMCAwLjI2IDAuMjQgMC41IDAuNSAwLjVoMTNjMC4yNiAwIDAuNS0wLjI0MSAwLjUtMC41di05YzAtMC4yNS0wLjI1LTAuNS0wLjUtMC41aC02LjVsLTItMnoiIGZpbGw9IiMwMDAiLz48L3N2Zz4K);
}

#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li.active,
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a:hover,
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a:focus,
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a:active, 
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a.selected,
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a.active, 
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li.active > a, 
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a:hover > a,
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a:focus > a,
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a:active > a, 
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a.selected > a,
#app-navigation:not(.vue) > ul > li a.active > a {
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: inset 4px 0 blue;
}

body{
  background: #1e272e;
}


/* CUSTOM */

.nav-icon-files:before{
    filter: invert(72%) sepia(3%) saturate(75%) hue-rotate(22deg) brightness(80%) contrast(91%);
}
```

```html
<div id="app-navigation">
    <ul class="with-icon">
        <li data-id="files" class="nav-files">
            <a href="#" class="nav-icon-files svg">Files</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```